# Resolve .htaccess additional error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403, errordocument

I'm a little confused. I have the following directories / files:

- root/
- - .htaccess
- - index.php
- - ed/
- - - .htaccess
- - - 403.php

There's an .htaccess in -root/ with the following content:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

ErrorDocument 403 /ed/403.php
```

In --ed/ there's an .htaccess with

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Problem: On calling -root/index.php I get the following error message:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**Why is there the additional 403 error for the ErrorDocument?!**

Thank you!

Comment: But I permitted access to exactly this directory (so a direct access to /ed/403.php works).

Comment: I suppose you need to allow the access of "ed" folder. Try putting another subfolder in root (mainpages...) and put your index.php and .htacces file, and allow from all the root folder

Comment: But then I'd need to give an absolute path to the error document and can't use the relative path to the root folder. That makes it a little more complicated to move the root folder where ever I want without a few changes.

Comment: I deleted my comment after a few seconds because I thought I had not enough evidence. .htaccess files are evaluated from top down; possibly Apache stops if it runs into the first deny. You could define rules on a per-directory-basis (and so define exceptions in the htaccess in your document root); maybe the satisfy directive may also be helpful. And remember that the error pages do not need to sit inside your document tree.

Comment: @syck: What do you mean with "per-directory-basis"? I now tried to set exceptiony with SetEnvIf Request_URI "(ed/)$" allow
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy all
I think Apache would not stop after running into the first "deny" because then I was not able to open "ed/403.php" directly (the "deny" from above is also "parsed" and then the "allow" within "ed" is "parsed" afterwards).

Comment: Have a look here >> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#satisfy << especially at the example.

Comment: This module seems not to be installed on my hosters server. I also tried the "satisfy" directive but it doesn't work. Still the same problem. Any other ideas?